# Children as text don't display in Text component in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

Why does data from GitHub API don't display as `children` in `Text` component called StyledDetail, created in styled components? Main screen which renders data is TabOneScreen , `UserData` in object containing typed user details extracted from GitHub API. `childern` which I want to display is certain feature of user like id, etc.

Below You can find main component StyledDetail component, and StyledDetailsWrapper.

```
    import React, { FC } from "react";
import { StyledDetailsWrapper, StyledDetail } from "./styles";

interface DetailsProps {
  selectionColor?: string | undefined;
}
export const DetailsData: FC<DetailsProps> = ({ children, selectionColor }) => {
  return (
    <StyledDetailsWrapper>
      <StyledDetail selectionColor={selectionColor}>{children}</StyledDetail>
    </StyledDetailsWrapper>
  );
};


    import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import styled from "styled-components/native";

export const StyledDetailsWrapper = styled(View)`
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 20px;
  width: 100px;
`;

export const StyledDetail = styled(Text)`
  ${(props: { selectionColor: string | undefined }) => props.selectionColor};
```

here is link to github repo :
https://github.com/marcinb1986/database/tree/main/components

Appreciate Your help

Comment: Please tidy up your code example into separate code blocks for clarity, separating the different component.

In React Native a string has to be inside a `Text` component. Is `StyledDetail` a `Text` component?

Also `<StyledDetailsWrapper {...{ color }}>` looks wrong. Can you please show your implementation of `StyledDetailsWrapper`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case `StyledDetail` is a `Text` component (i.e. `const StyledDetail = styled.Text ...`) you can either

- Display all data by combining it into a template string:

  ```
  <DetailsData>
    {userData && `${userData.id}, ${userData.location}, ${userData.created_at}`}
  </DetailsData>
  ```
- Use `StyledDetail` inside `TabOneScreen` to display each text individually as styled with `StyledDetail`:

  ```
  <DetailsData>
    <StyledDetail>{userData && userData.id}</StyledDetail>
    <StyledDetail>{userData && userData.location}</StyledDetail>
    <StyledDetail>{userData && userData.created_atd}</StyledDetail>
  </DetailsData>
  ```